# Calculate/Display NSTableView column sum

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I’m updating an Objective-C app. I have an NSTableView w/ 2 columns. Column 2 binding: set to arrayController, arrangedObjects, and the Model Key is set to a defined Entity Attribute.

I have Attribute type set to “Float.” I added a numberFormatter to the column with its format set to “Currency.” Everything (Add, Delete, Save, etc.) works as expected. What I would like to do is update an independent textField below the table column to display the running sum of the currency values populating the column.

The updating in the sum textField doesn’t need to update dynamically. I can set up a separate action to manually initialize a calculation of the existing column values.

How can I get this done?

Comment: What is the question, how to calculate the sum from your data or how to display a text field at the bottom of the column? Core Data? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Core Data, yes. The table populates as intended. And I can display (in a textField) the total number entries that populate the table using count. model key path binding. One column includes currency values.  I need to display the sum of the column entries in a textfield as well. How would I set up bindings for textField to display the sum of column entries?  Is there more to it than implementing @sum. model key path binding?

Comment: Bind to the array controller, arrangedObjects, `@sum.modelKey`?

Comment: Yes. I tried. It was throwing an exception and freezing the table. Not sure why. I solved it by unhooking the binding and adding code for value, object, and keyPath in awakeFromNib. Now it all works? I'm not exactly sure whey the binding in IB was problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the text field to the array controller

Controller key: `arrangedObjects`

Model Key Path: `@sum.modelKey`

The sum value is the same type as the summed values. Add a number formatter to the text field with the same settings as the formatter of the cell in the column.